# Get required fields and check if true or false

Tags: jquery, html, required

I need to change an application which sets inputs to `required="true"` or `required="false"`. My problem here is when I try to get all of inputs which are required, I just get all of them even the `false` one.

What I tried:

`$('input[required=true')` -> gets all of them

```
var $input = $('input');
$.each($input, function(sKey, sValue){
    if($('#' + sValue.id).prop('required') == "true"){
        //Gets all even the false one
    }

    if($('#' + sValue.id).prop('required')){
        //Gets all even the false one
    }

    if($('#' + sValue.id).attr('required') == "true"){
        //Gets all even the false one
    }

    if($('#' + sValue.id).attr('required') == "required"){
        //Gets all even the false one
    }

    if($('#' + sValue.id).attr('required') == "required"){
        //Gets all even the false one
    }

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log($("input[required='true']").length);` works fine for me in Chrome when the elements are hard coded in the HTML. Are they being dynamically generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like following.

```
   var input = $('input');

    $.each(input, function (sKey, sValue) {
        if (sValue.outerHTML.contains('required="true"')) {
            //Gets all true
        }
    })
```

Comment: I know that, that's why it's a dumbass application. I need to edit it, but can not change their idiot-like solution for the required fields. No why to distiguish true or false?

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding check the answer now.

Comment: Nothing to sry about. I am just angry at the developer. They are even using iFrames and it's a 2015 web application. Thank you for your answer. This works fine, just like that `$("input[required='true']` :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.each($('input[required=true]'), function(sKey, sValue){
    console.log(sValue);
});
```

will get you input having attribute `required='true'`.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbL2494r/2/),